# Import data dump into PDB

Tags: oracle12c

I have a data dump which is being created using exp command from 10g server. I want to import that into one of PDB database.

I tried to do like `imp system/******@pdb file=test.dmp full=y ignore=y commit=y log=imp_test.log` but it does not connects.

I have also tried `imp system/*******@CDB1:1521/pdb file=test.dmp full=y ignore=y commit=y log=imp_test.log`

Please, can you let me know how can I achieve this?

Comment: what is the name of the pdb?

Answer (score 0):

It could work with `imp pdb file=test.dmp full=y ignore=y commit=y log=imp_test.log`
I mean by removing `system/******@` from your first example.
I was able to connect with this method. The drawback is that you have to specify your user name (system) and password manually.